# Mvc 6 taghelper asp-action route not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm using Areas in Mvc 6 and trying to route to each specific area. 
For example I have this:

My controller looks is decorated with a Area and route attribute, like so:

```
[Authorize]
[Area("Test")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
```

Then, I have two HTTPGET methods defined like below:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new TestViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new TestViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Finally my form looks like this:

```
    <form asp-route-area="Test" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Create" asp-antiforgery="false" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Generate test"/>
    </form>
```

When I try to post the form it throws the following:

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following
>   actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> Areas.Test.Controllers.TestController.Index
>
> Areas.Test.Controllers.TestController.Create

You would think that it would bind to my Create method when I define it in the asp-action, but when I check the rendered markup of the form it looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="/Test/Test">
        <input type="submit" value="Generate test">
 </form>
```

My method Create isn't handled, It only renders Test/Test (area/controller).

I've also tried to decorate my method with `[Route("Create")]` and `[HttpGet("Create")]` without results.

Am I missing out on something obvious here?

Comment: which version of framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `RC1` then you can't use areas in tag helpers.

Areas in tag helpers are supported in `RC2` [link to issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4013)